# Loop through a game board represented by a matrix and analyze all possible 3 in a row winning positions

Tags: javascript

I have a 6 x 6 game board, represented by the following array:

```
gameBoard= [
        0 , 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
        6 , 7, 8, 9,10,11,
        12,13,14,15,16,17,
        18,19,20,21,22,23,
        24,25,26,27,28,29,
        30,31,32,33,34,35
    ]
```

I am working on a game of hybrid tic tac toe.

Here is the first step (CPU's turn):

Loop through each position of the board

```
for(var i=0, len = gameBoard.length; i < len; i++){
}
```

Now, lets say I am at position 8.

My logic is to check the surrounding positions (1,2,3,7,9,13,14,15) for:

- if there is an "X" (opponent), score = 0;
- if there is a blank space, sc0re = 1;
- if there is a "0", score = 2

At the end, store everything inside an array.

The position with the biggest score from that array, would be to position that the CPU will play.

**Finally, the question: how would you code the above logic inside the for loop?**, keeping in mind there are positions like 0,1,2,4... which aren't surrounded by other positions so we can't use the logic above everywhere.

Here is what I have tried and thinking of building on:

```
function scoreCalc(pos){
        console.log("score: "+pos);
        var score = 0,
            pocket;
        pocket = jQuery(document).find('[data-kcpos="'+pos+'"]');
        if(jQuery(pocket).hasClass("blank")){
            score += 1;
        } else if(jQuery(pocket).text() == "x"){
            score += 0;
        } else if(jQuery(pocket).text() == "0"){
            score += 2;
        }
        console.log("score: "+score);
        return score;
    }


function minimax(){

        var pos,
            testMargin,
            toTest,
            pocket,
            score,
            toTestScore,
            totalScore = new Array();

        for(var i=0, len = gameBoard.length; i < len; i++){
            score = 0;
            pos = gameBoard[i];
            // Check if pocket is empty
            pocket = jQuery(document).find('[data-kcpos="'+pos+'"]');
            if(jQuery(pocket).hasClass("blank")){
                // Check to see if we have a margin
                testMargin = jQuery.inArray(pos, margins);
                if(testMargin != -1){ // If we have a margin

                } else {
                    // Test the pocket above
                    toTest = pos - 6;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the pocket bellow
                    toTest = pos + 6;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the pocket to the left
                    toTest = pos - 1;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the pocket to the right
                    toTest = pos + 1;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the top left diagonal
                    toTest = pos - 7;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the bottom right diagonal
                    toTest = pos + 7;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the top right diagonal
                    toTest = pos - 5;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;

                    // Test the bottom left diagonal
                    toTest = pos + 5;
                    toTestScore = scoreCalc(toTest);
                    score += toTestScore;
                }
                totalScore.push({key: pos, val: score});
            }
        }
        // Sort the array
        totalScore.sort(function descending(a,b){
             return b.val - a.val;
        });

        pocket = jQuery(document).find('[data-kcpos="'+totalScore[0].key+'"]');
        jQuery(pocket).find(".ui-btn-text").text("0");
        jQuery(pocket).removeClass("blank");

        return totalScore;
    }
```

Comment: Your question shows zero personal research and effort.

Comment: soo you want us to create your AI? XD

Comment: Sorry about that, posted what I was thinking of.

Comment: K i'll try to help you. Posting an answer in a few sec but don't get me wrong i'll just give you hints, not do all your work ;)

Comment: I'm not afraid of hard work, it's just this is my first time coding an algo and I feel like I'm not doing it right :) - in my logic there is a big issue - the positions 0,1,2,3,4,5 ... essentially the margins of the matrix

Comment: I read about the minmax algo, and this is the closest I could think of getting to it - use the function I have posted to analyze and score the CPU and playes moves - and than intersect the two arrays - find the move with the biggest score for the CPU and the lowest score for the player

Comment: Create some properties for each array position, noting their surrounding element's number/value within it and storing all of those in the property (being an array). Such as : `gameboard[0]['siblings'] = [1,6,7];` or as a real property/attribute: `gameboard[0].siblings = [1,6,7];`

Answer (score 0):

Using a two dimensional array might make it easier to check surrounding areas.  That way you'll know the position by row and column, and can check [row-1, col-1], [row-1,col],[row-1, col+1] etc...  That will make checking the corner cases like 0 or top row cases easier instead of knowing that in a 36 element array the first 6 are the first row.  Your players position would be an x, y coordinate, which you could get from your board array `gameboard[x][y]`.

The 2D array will make checking the edge cases easier, and might make your game logic a little easier to understand.  Plus it'll give you some flexibility for changing the board size if you desire.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So a few hints:

First:
 Make the array this way:

```
gameBoard= [
        [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ],
        [ "", "", "", "", "", "" ]
    ]
```

by using it liek this you can access rows easier for the search with gameBoard[x][y].

Second: 
 By altering the array you can check all cells like this:

write a function to do the checking (let's say checkCell(x,y))

and check with the following pairs: (x,y),(x-1,y),(x+1,y),(x,y+1),(x,y-1),(x-1,y-1),(x+1,y-1),(x+1,y+1). ( checking (x,y) is to see if it's empty)

And sum the scores. Also if x,y>5 or x,y<0 you should return 0 from the checkCell function :)

Third:
 no need to store all values. Just store one variable maxScore, maxScoreIndexX and maxScoreIndexY which start as 0 and you do the following step: 
if([sum of all nearby cell scores]>maxScore) { 
maxScore=[sum of all nearby cell scores]; 
maxScoreIndexX = currentX;
 maxScoreY=currentY
}

That way in the end you will have the best score and it's location stored in those 3 values.

Comment: Ty very much, this is great and it's something I can work with. I will definitely post my results. ;) Ty again!

Comment: yw, but you should try more things on your own ;)

Comment: I am a beginner, I would not have thought of that... not in many, many days :)